# Custom Control won't fill dock correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control that was made to be plugged into my application, this was done because it will be used multiple times in the application. Why rebuild the wheel when I can just spit shine it and give it another whirl. Anyway, I have it Dock/Filled into my main application in a tabpage, the problem is it doesn't fill the bottom. Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhYv6.gif)

Comment: Is there another control in that tab space?  Do you have the MaximumSize property set for the custom control?

Comment: Does the TabControl itself stretch down there?  Should the TabControl be Dock Filled as well?

Comment: @LarsTech There is no controls in that space, I made that tab fresh and put my custom control in it, the MaximumSize property is set to 0,0 default.

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes the TabControl does go down there, my other 2 tabs go down there just fine. The TabControl is already Dock Filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further fiddling with the properties of my custom control. I have fixed the issue if it not going further down my tabpage.

I set the following properties on my Custom Control:
    
    `AutoSize = True
    AutoSizeMode = GrowAndStrink`